# how to adjust the header position so that it is slightly to the middle or inward?

Tags: html, css, position

How do I adjust the position of the header that has been marked as in the picture slightly inward or in the top center?.[image]

```
.header{
    display:flex;
    position:relative;
}
.header h1{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    color:black;
    background:lightblue;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    border:3px solid lightblue;
    border-radius:8px;
    
}
```

this is the script i'm trying to set the position in css.I'm still a beginner so please help to solve this problem, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.header{
width:50%,
margin:auto;
}

Answer (score 1):

There are several things.

If you want the header fixed, put position fixed in the header not in the H1

```
.header{
    display:flex;
    position:fixed;
}
```

Now because the header has display flex, add justify content center:

```
.header{
    display:flex;
    position:fixed;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Final

```
.header{
    display:flex;
    position:fixed;
    justify-content: center;
    width:100%;
}
.header h1{
    color:black;
    background:lightblue;
    padding:5px;
    border:3px solid lightblue;
    border-radius:8px;    
}
```

That could work.
If you want to learn more on display flex, check here:
[css display flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)